# rx-node writeToStream not emitting output to process.stdout

Tags: rxjs

I have been using the node extensions for RX (rx-node) and am having trouble using a particular function, writeToStream.

The following example does not emit any values to the console (process.stdout):

```
var Rx = require('rx');
var RxNode = require('rx-node');
var source = Rx.Observable.range(0, 5);
var subscription = RxNode.writeToStream(source, process.stdout, 'utf8');
```

I have tried using an alternative using a simple subscriptions which works fine (I write the output from "next" directly to the console) but that is a work-around to getting the writeToStream working.

Any ideas what I amy need to do to get the writeToStream working?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is a bug in the 1.0 version of rx-node. It has been fixed in the latest [versions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx-node/pull/8). However these fixes are not yet on npm, the best fix right now is to download the [master source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx-node/master/index.js) directly (it's just one file).

**Update 1**  The fix is now live on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-node) as of version 1.0.1

Comment: Great to see it fixed.  I will use the one from master source.  Thanks!